# OSX: silently run .app

Tags: macos, qt, silent-installer

Do someone know if there is a way to silently install an .app from a DMG using command line?

**I'm not talking about apps that you have to copy to /Applications nor about the .pkg ones.**

Example: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.0/qt-mac-opensource-5.2.0-clang-offline.dmg

Comment: Have you read this? http://commandlinemac.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/installing-dmg-application-from-command.html

Comment: Is this still unresolved more than one year later??

Answer (score 0):

.app packages are not meant to be installed silently.  The only way you will be able to do what you want is by adding **open -a application.app** to execute it per the instructions given above, so for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

hdiutil attach -mountpoint /your-directory-path/installation-file.dmg
sudo cp -R /volumes/your-app-path-here/app-name.app /Applications
hdiutil detach /volumes/your-app-path-here/
open -a /Applications/applicationname.app
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find the steps below to perform this:

1) hdiutil attach -mountpoint yourpath qt-mac-opensource-5.2.0-clang-offline.dmg

2) sudo cp -R your-.app-file-in-yourpath /Applications (this step might be .pkg file, and cannot verify the Qt installer right now).

3) hdiutil detach yourpath

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned above, I'm talking about app that need to be installed, not just copied to /Applications.

Comment: @deadbird: yes, and this is the way to do it. What is your concern? Something is not working after installing Qt like this?

Comment: The aim is to install qt-whatever.app silently from command line, ie without displaying the GUI.

Comment: @deadbird: sure, so what is the problem with my steps? That will do that as far as I can tell. I have not tested myself just now, but based on some investigation, it should do it. Are you facing some real issues?

Comment: The problem is on step 2. On this step you copy the .app into /Applications. This is fine in most cases. Here, the .app is an installer that needs to be launched for Qt to be installed. My aim here is to launch this installer from command line (with open for instance) but without displaying the GUI (ie: "silently").

Comment: @deadbird: could you please give a concrete example why that is a problem, provided you also considered the .pkg in the bracket?

Comment: Try downloading Qt with the link I provided, maybe you'll see what I mean ;)

Comment: @deadbird: as I wrote, I cannot do that currently, but maybe later. Could you please share the real issue rather than making this conversation long? :)